# How to use prefetch_related with Django's DetailView

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-orm

I want to use `prefetch_related` with `Django's DetailView`.

Model:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='customer name',
        max_length=100
    )
    # Other fields

class Packet(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        Customer
    )
    # Other fields

class Credit(models.Model)   :
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        Customer
    )
    # Other fields
```

View:

```
class CustomerDetailsView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Customer
    http_method_names = ['get']
    template_name = 'detail_templates/customer_details.html'
```

Templates:

```
{% for p in object.packet_set %}
    {{ do something }}
{% endif %}

{% for p in object.credit_set %}
    {{ do something }}
{% endif %}
```

Tried:

```
class CustomerDetailsView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Customer
    http_method_names = ['get']
    template_name = 'detail_templates/customer_details.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(CustomerDetailsView, self).get_queryset()
        pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg, None)
        return queryset.filter(id=pk).prefetch_related('packet_set', 'credit_set')
```

`debug_toolbar shows no improvement`. 
How do I `prefetch_related packet and credit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no sense to use `prefetch_related()` in the `DetailView`.  This view loads the single master object with `get()` while `prefetch_related()` is usable for loading related objects of multiple master objects.

Comment: The code from you link has several errors and doesn't optimize anything.  It is a reasonable intention to use `prefetch_related()` in the `ListView` but don't bother to do it in the `DetailView`.

Comment: detail views can load nested lists of related objects in which case you need to use prefetch related.

Answer (score 2):

You can define get_queryset method, it's called inside get_object

```
class CustomerDetailsView(DetailView):
    ...
    def get_queryset(*args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwrags) \
            .prefetch_related("packet_set", "credit_set")
```